# Using isc-dhcp-server along side an existing DHCP server for PXE

Tags: networking, maas, dhcp, pxe, tftp

This may be more of a networking question but very long story short, I'm in the process of setting up a PXEBoot server (TFTP/HTTP) to automate network installs of Linux and the last thing I need to do/test is how to make it work within an existing DHCP environment.  I've gone ahead and tested/documented the steps on how to configure DHCP Options 60 & 67 on an existing DHCP server.  It works fine as long as your DHCP server can provide the logic necessary to determine the platform difference between a BIOS based or a UEFI based system.

The other method to configure this to install isc-dhcp-server on your TFTP server and either place it in the same subnet or modify the IP Helper options on your routers so its receives the DHCP REQ's.  This is what I need is some help understanding how this is supposed to work.

Normally, when designing a subnet with multiple DHCP servers, unless the DHCP servers have some way to replicate or notify each other of which IP's it's handed out, to avoid IP address conflicts you configure them to hand out ranges that don't overlap.

So imagine (for simplicity sake) a flat 192.168.1.0/24 network with an existing DHCP server configured to issue out IP's for the entire range.  Is there a way to configure isc-dhcp-server's dhcpd.conf file to only issue the DHCP Options 60/67 and let the existing server hand out remaining network info?

OR... am I expected to redesign my network to only hand out half of the IP's from the existing DHCP server, and the other half from the new isc-dhcp-server?  If this is the case, and I only have 1 of the 2 DHCP servers configured to hand out DHCP Options 60/67 won't I run into an issue where sometimes when booting from the network it will get it's info from the DHCP server that doesn't have the necessary information?

I guess what I'm really looking for is for someone who has this all working to explain at a high level how this is all supposed to work together avoiding IP address conflicts.

Thx for any help or guidance!

Comment: you can only have one dhcp server for a subnet.  what you need is to configure the existing one as a dhcp relay (which might not be possible) and then use the main isc one via that dhcp relay.  or redesign your network.  theres unfortunately no other way around it.

Comment: Assuming you're running an up-to-date release of Ubuntu  (you didn't say), you should be able to set up PXE with `netplan`. Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.